# API Management connector unusable in Logic Apps after management API upgrade

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-api-management, connector

A message from Advisor told me that the management API for Azure API Management was to be upgraded to a newer version and a 'quick fix' button was included to help adjusting some parameters. As I thought everything was fine in my setup, I clicked the button and it failed due to some misconfigured firewall rules. I quickly fixed the rules and saw no more error messages when checking service status, so I was convinced the issue was done. Surprise, it wasn't...

After this, I can no longer use the API Management connector inside logic apps. If I try to create a new logic app, it gives me the error message below. If I try to edit an existing logic app, the API management blocks just show a message about not being accessible and I get an error message saying I cannot save any changes since swagger is not available.

This is the error message when using the connector in a new logic app:
*"API version query parameter is not specified or was specified incorrectly. Supported versions: 2021-08-01,2021-12-01-preview,2022-04-01-preview,2022-08-01,2022-09-01-preview,2023-03-01-preview,2023-05-01-preview,2023-09-01-preview Example query param format: api-version=SupportedVersion"*

Everything else works fine and I have no problems calling API management by using the http connector. As I only work through the Azure Portal, I can't see what's causing this.

The API management instance is obviously now running on the new management API version and there's a policy set that won't allow older versions. The advisor message is still triggered when I try to access the APIM connector in a logic app, but the 'quick fix' button is gone.

I sadly have no idea whatsoever on where to even begin with this issue. Shouldn't the APIM logic app connector be automatically updated as well, or is there some manual action I have to perform? Please help..

Update:
Screenshots of errors in Logic Apps

[image: Modifying an existing Logic App]

[image: Adding a new Azure API Management connector #1]

[image: Adding a new Azure API Management connector #2]

Comment: Can you please share some screenshots just to have a better clarity on the problem you are facing as in how you are doing it or which management API you are using?

Comment: I've added screenshots of my Logic Apps errors now. Since I'm using the portal only, I have no clue which management API version is being used. From the errors it seems like the Logic App API Management connector is still using an older version for some reason I don't understand.

Comment: Can you create a new APIM instance and try on that as I am able to use the APIM connector in logic app

Comment: @Anders
Go to your API Management Service -> Management API -> Management API Settings and set the "Enforce minimum API version" to "Yes". Make sure that you have no deployments that use API versions older than 2021-08-01 as they will start failing after this change

Comment: @MoHaidar:
"Enforce minimum API version" has been set to "Yes" by the Advisor action.

Comment: @IkhtesamAfrin: Creating a new APIM instance would maybe be an option, but since I only work through the portal, I can't really see how it should be done. Something must have failed to execute in the Advisor script since the connector is no longer working, but I have no idea what it tried to do. There was a description of the actions, but it was lost when the action button disappeared.

Comment: @Markus-Meyer where you ever able to resolve this issue? This problem began for me after enforcing the minimum API version in our APIM and now I can't even save any logic app that uses the APIM connector for the APIM. I get the same error shown in your screenshot when trying to add new connector.

Answer (score 0):

2 options:

1. Wait for Microsoft to fix the `Azure API Management` connector so that it works even after enforcing the minimum API version in the API Management service.

or

2. Replace the `Azure API Management` actions in your workflows with [`HTTP`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-http?tabs=consumption) actions.